# Passing props to makeStyles react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, material-ui

I have this component

```
 const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles(props);

  return (
    <div
      className={classes.divBackground}
      backgroundImageLink={props.product?.image}
      sx={{ position: "relative" }}
    ></div>
  );
};


export default MyComponent;
```

I am trying to pass **backgroundImage** link in props and trying to put into makeStyles

```
export default makeStyles(props => ({
    divBackground:{
        background:`url("${props.backgroundImageLink}")`,
    }
}));
```

But this does not works

& I am getting this warning in console

```
index.js:1 Warning: React does not recognize the `backgroundImage` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `backgroundimage` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
```

Comment: backgroundImage seems a reserved keyword in ReactJs, why dont you try someother name?

Comment: No changed props name to 'backgroundImageLink' still no luck

Comment: it may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57586654/styled-component-attrs-react-does-not-recognize-prop

Comment: `background:`url("${props.backgroundImageLink` it must be `backgroundImage:`url("${props.backgroundImageLink`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not supposed to pass arbitrary attributes to the native elements (`div` in this case) because it doesn't do anything. The prop only works when passed in `useStyles`:

```
export default makeStyles({
  divBackground: {
    background: props => `url("${props.product?.image}")`,
  }
});
```

#### Usage

```
 const MyComponent = (props) => {
  // you only need to pass the props here. useStyles will then use the
  // prop.product.image to create the background property, generate a
  // stylesheet and return the class name for you.
  const classes = useStyles(props);

  return (
    <div
      className={classes.divBackground}
      // remove this line -----> backgroundImageLink={props.product?.image}
      sx={{ position: "relative" }}
    ></div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles(props)();

  return (
    <div
      className={classes.divBackground}
      backgroundImageLink={props.product?.image}
      sx={{ position: "relative" }}
    ></div>
  );
};


export default MyComponent;
```

then :

```
export default useStyles=(props)=>makeStyles(()=> ({
    divBackground:{
        background:`url("${props.backgroundImageLink}")`,
    }
}));
```