# Styled Components not being recognized in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components, react-typescript, react-flow

I have the following Styled component (not posting complete, doesn't make any difference):
It extends `Handle` (and `HandleProps`) from `'reactflow'` library

```
interface CustomHandleProps extends HandleProps {
  istarget?: boolean;
  zoomedout?: boolean;
  placement: number;
  placementOffset: string;
  nodeSize: string;
  titleMaxLength?: 1 | 2;
  showTitle?: string;
  customTitle?: PointTitleCustomization;
  format?: PointFormat;
}

export const CustomHandle = styled(Handle).attrs(({ type }) => ({ type }))<CustomHandleProps>`
  width: ${({ nodeSize }) => nodeSize};
  height: ${({ nodeSize }) => nodeSize};
  border-radius: ${({ format }) => (format ? (format === 'circle' ? '50%' : '0') : '50%')};
  display: flex;
  border: ${({ zoomedout }) => (!zoomedout ? ' 1px solid #fff' : 'none')};
...
`
```

And it's being used like:

```
import * as Styled from './diagram-card-edge.styles';
<Styled.CustomHandle
  key={`${edgePosition}-${type}-${index}-${nodeData.id}`}
  id={`${edgePosition}-${type}-${index}-${nodeData.id}`}
  position={position}
  istarget={isTarget}
  type={type}
  zoomedout={zoomedOut}
  isConnectable={!zoomedOut}
  placement={calcEdgePlacement(
    index,
    nodeData.edges[edgePosition]?.nodes as number,
    nodeData.edges[edgePosition]?.alignOffset,
    nodeData.edges[edgePosition]?.align
  )}
  isConnectableStart={!nodeData.lockDiagram}
  placementOffset="-0.3rem"
  nodeSize="0.5rem"
/>;
```

But React doesn't seem to recognize it as a Styled component, getting errors like:

> Warning: React does not recognize the `nodeSize` prop on a DOM
> element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom
> attribute, spell it as lowercase `nodesize` instead. If you
> accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM
> element.
> or
> Warning: React does not recognize the `placementOffset` prop on a DOM
> element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom
> attribute, spell it as lowercase `placementoffset` instead. If you
> accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM
> element.

or

> Warning: Received `false` for a non-boolean attribute `zoomedout`.
>
> If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead:
> zoomedout="false" or zoomedout={value.toString()}.
>
> If you used to conditionally omit it with zoomedout={condition &&
> value}, pass zoomedout={condition ? value : undefined} instead.

The values of the attrs are being passed correctly in the component, I checked the logs for it.
I tried to do some modifications like the ones in [styled-component .attrs - React does not recognize prop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57586654/styled-component-attrs-react-does-not-recognize-prop) , but none seemed to work.

**React version: 17.0.2
Styled-Components version: 5.3.5**

Comment: Have you tried using `<CustomHandle>` instead of `<Styled.CustomHandle>`?

Comment: yes, I'm using Styled because of `import * as Styled from './diagram-card-edge.styles';`

Comment: The DOM prop warnings can arise when you pass all props through to a DOM element, e.g. `(props) => <div {...props}>...</div>` because props like "nodeSize" get passed through to the div.

Comment: Just as @ray said, `Handle` from `react-flow` pass any additional props down to the `<div>`, causing this problem (see https://github.com/wbkd/react-flow/blob/52d29fe13e1397d69cd55136c2387982c8f787b4/packages/core/src/components/Handle/index.tsx#L187)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [styled component error "it looks like an unknown prop "responsive" is sent through to the DOM, which will likely trigger a React console error."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76857070/styled-component-error-it-looks-like-an-unknown-prop-responsive-is-sent-throu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there was 2 problems here:
First and foremost, it was missing the main import of reactflow styles, which was breaking a lot of stuff in the code

```
import 'reactflow/dist/style.css';
```

Second, when needed to pass more props and for them to be recognized, you need to use withConfig and shouldForwardProp
so the example in the question has become:

```
export const CustomHandle = styled(Handle).withConfig({
    shouldForwardProp: (prop) =>
        !['istarget', 'zoomedout', 'cardEdgeHandlePositionOffset', 'cardEdgeHandleDimensions'].includes(prop)
})<CustomHandleProps>`
...
```

and this is how I managed to fix the warnings of props and the styling of the custom reactflow component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `styled-components` [transient props](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#transient-props) by adding a dollar sign (`$`) prefix to the prop name:

```
<Styled.CustomHandle
  $nodeSize="0.5rem"
/>
```

This allows you to skip certain props to be passed down.